# Sharing of Accounts in Enterprise Territory Management

Tags: sharing, einstein-analytics, territory-management

I struggle a bit with the ETM topic. I have set up ETM in SF and defined the dataflow to cover ETM sharing logic (with security predicate) in Analytics. However when I checked for a specific user I find a specific Account visible to that user even if the user is not assigned to a territory this Account is assigned to.

In other words this account should not be visible to this user according to ETM.

I wonder what the reason is. Could it be that this user gets access to the account as the user is part of a public group with users in that public group that actually have access?

Answer (score 2):

> Could it be that this user gets access to the account as the user is part of a public group with users in that public group that actually have access?

Yes. That could be one of the reasons. While Territory Management is in use, it does not affect the [record sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=territories_def.htm&type=5), those still remain in effect.

> Account ownership and its effect on record sharing remains valid and unchanged when territory management is in use.

Additionally if you also have a Role Hierarchy and that the User has access to the Account through Role Hierarchy, that could be a possible reason too. When Role Hierarchy is also in place, the the most permissive access between Territory Hierarchy vs. Role Hierarchy is granted.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated in other answers any additional sharing is still applied with Territory Management and the most permissive wins.

You can check why a user has access to an account by querying the [AccountShare](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountshare.htm) table

```
SELECT Rowcause FROM AccountShare WHERE AccountID=x AND UserOrGroupId=id
```

Alternatively in Classic you can add the share button to the layout. This will take you to a page where you can see everyone who has access and what mechanism is granting it.